# for(auto [a,b]:m) it works but marked as red color in vs code

Tags: c++, visual-studio-code

in my c++ program i used a

```
vector<vector<pair<int,int>>>adj;
```

when i try to iterate as

```
for(auto [a,x]:adj[nd]){
}
```

[a,x] is marked red as error but after execution the program it works as well as it shows a warning

```
code1.cpp: In member function 'void Graph::dfs(int)':
code1.cpp:65:12: warning: structured bindings only available with -std=c++17 or -std=gnu++17
   for(auto [u,x]:adj[nd]){
```

how can i fixed it ?

Comment: It sounds like the C++ version your Intellisense is set to differs from the C++ version you're actually compiling against.

Comment: Look at this [sample c_cpp_properties.json file](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/cpp/c-cpp-properties-schema-reference), especially where it says `"cppStandard": "c++17",`

Comment: Intellisense (which is what generates the red squiggles) is *not* the compiler and it's sometimes wrong. Simple as that.

Comment: @JesperJuhl Yes, but in this case the intellisense is misconfigured. Surely it can highlight structured bindings correctly.

Answer (score 1):

You have a `vector` of `vector<pair>`

So a basic iteration prior to C++ 17 is this:

```
for(auto& vec : adj) {
    for (auto& p : vec) {
       int a = p.first;
       int x = p.second;
    }
}
```

If you can you change your build environment to build with  `-std=c++17` (msvc: `/std:c++17`), you can do this:

```
for(auto& vec : adj) {
    for (auto& [a,x] : vec) {  // remove the & if yot don't want a and x to be references, but instead copies

    }
}
```

Comment: Why would you avoid C++17 features, when you can fix intellisense config?

Comment: @HolyBlackCat - perhaps the OP works on a team that has a code base that isn't enabled for latest C++ standard.

Comment: @selbie We have 2023 and C++17 is available for many years. We did not talk about "latest", we talk about outdated tools :-)